# Add columns and Arithmetic with Time in R

Tags: r, math, time-series

I have a table in .csv format with 12K rows like below:

```
St.      date        Rgtime      RadTime       Rain      dBZ 
3613006 20130113     0:06:00      0:06:00       2      -10.625 
3613006 20130113     0:16:00      0:16:00       7      -11.75 
3613006 20130113     0:26:00      0:26:00       1      -10.5625 
3613006 20130113     0:36:00      0:36:00       9      -11.28125 
3613006 20130113     0:46:00      0:46:00       3      -10.34375 
3613006 20130113     0:56:00      0:56:00       8      -11.6875 
3613006 20130113     1:06:00      1:06:00       9      -16 
3613006 20130113     1:16:00      1:16:00       6      -25.3125 
3613006 20130113     1:26:00      1:26:00       1      -16.3125 
3613006 20130113     1:36:00      1:36:00       0      -20.71875
```

1. $RgTime - 10 minutes  AS RadTimeNew
2. relevant dBZ to RadTimeNew  AS dBZ.New .

dBZ.new should find match variable in Radtime and dBZ .

Expected result:

```
St.      date        Rgtime     RadTime    Rain      dBZ        RadTimeNew    dBZ.New 
3613006 20130113   0:06:00      0:06:00    2       -10.625           NA         NA 
3613006 20130113   0:16:00      0:16:00    7       -11.75         0:06:00    -10.625 
3613006 20130113   0:26:00      0:26:00    1       -10.5625       0:16:00    -11.75 
3613006 20130113   0:36:00      0:36:00    9       -11.28125      0:26:00    -10.5625 
3613006 20130113   0:46:00      0:46:00    3       -10.34375      0:36:00    -11.28125 
3613006 20130113   0:56:00      0:56:00    8       -11.6875       0:46:00    -10.34375 
3613006 20130113   1:06:00      1:06:00    9       -16            0:56:00    -11.6875 
3613006 20130113   1:16:00      1:16:00    6       -25.3125       1:06:00    -16 
3613006 20130113   1:26:00      1:26:00    1       -16.3125       1:16:00    -25.3125 
3613006 20130113   1:36:00      1:36:00    0       -20.7187       1:26:00    -16.3125
```

I tried to used lag(), but my data time is not continues and there are some error. So I am looking for a new script ( loop , if ,....)  to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to subtract those 10 minutes. I assume that your column denotes elapsed time, not time of the day. Since such might exceed 24 hours, I'd rather not go via a date-and-time data type like POSIXct, but instead do the math myself, like this:

```
hms <- t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Rgtime), ":"), as.integer))
secs <- (hms[,1]*60 + hms[,2])*60 + hms[,3] - 10*60
hms <- matrix(as.integer(c(secs %/% 3600, secs %/% 60 %% 60, secs %% 60)),
              ncol=3)
data$RadTimeNew <- sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d", hms[,1], hms[,2], hms[,3])
data$RadTimeNew[secs < 0] <- NA
```

Then you want to find matching values. A merge can do that for you:

```
data <- merge(data, data.frame(RadTimeNew=data$RadTime, dBZ.New=data$dBZ),
              all.x=TRUE)
```

If you want to, you can reorder the columns of the result:

```
data <- data[c(2,3,4,5,6,7,1,8)]
```

---

As an alternative, you could do something like this:

```
mylag <- function(v) v[c(NA,1:length(v)-1)]
data$RadTimeNew <- mylag(data$RadTime)
data$dBZ.New <- mylag(data$dBZ)
hmsstr2secs <- function(str) {
    hms <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(str), ":"), as.integer)
    return ((hms[1,]*60 + hms[2,])*60 + hms[3,])
}
nomatch <- (hmsstr2secs(data$Rgtime) - 600 != mylag(hmsstr2secs(data$RadTime)))
data$RadTimeNew[nomatch] <- NA
data$dBZ.New[nomatch] <- NA
```

The function `mylag` simply prepends `NA` to its argument and drops the last element instead. I use this to simply append shifted versions of your two columns. But as you said that there might be gaps, we have to find those. So I turn both the `RadTime` and `Rgtime` columns into seconds, and check whether they differ by 10 minutes. For those rows where that is not the case, I set `RadTimeNew` and `dBZ.New` to `NA`. If I had tried to write `hmsstr2secs(data$RadTimeNew)` instead of `mylag(hmsstr2secs(data$RadTime))`, that would have failed since `hmsstr2secs` isn't designed to deal with `NA` in its input.

This version might be faster than the one above, since it doesn't have to compare every row with every other row, like the `merge` does, but instead can exploit the fact that if there is a match at all, it is between consecutive rows. It also avoids the conversion from seconds to h:mm:ss strings, which means it is more robust in case you sometimes have dates formatted differently, in terms of leading zeros or the likes.

One difference in the result is the fact that if we don't have a match, this version here will have `NA` in the `RadTimeNew` column, while the version above had the computed time which didn't match up.

Comment: Hi @MvG. The alternative code is working well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AliSeif: When you say that the alternative code worked well, does that imply that my first code did not work for you? In what way? Since others might want to benefit from your question, I'd like to fix any issues that might have.